# Object pascal. Read textfile to variable of WideChar

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have my function determines if WideChar var is a letter:

```
function TWordCounter.IsAlpha(ch: WideChar): boolean;
Begin
    ch := upcase(ch);
    isalpha := (((ch >='A') and (ch <='Z')) or ((ch >='А') and (ch <='Я')));
end;
```

Here is code part using `IsAlpha` function:

```
Procedure TWordCounter.CountWords(path: string);
    var
        inputFile: TextFile;
        chr: WideChar;
        inWord: boolean;
        currentWord: string[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
Begin
    SetLength(wordArray, 0);
    if (not FileExists(path)) then begin
        raise Exception.Create('Указанный путь не ведет к текстовому файлу');
        exit;
    end;
    SetLength(wordArray, BASE_WORD_ARRAY_LENGTH);
    currentArrayLimit := BASE_WORD_ARRAY_LENGTH;
    currentArrayLength := 0;
    AssignFile(inputFile, path);
    Reset(inputFile);
    inWord := false;
    currentWord := '';
    while not eof(inputFile) do begin
        read(inputFile, chr);
        if (isAlpha(chr)) then begin
            inWord := true;
            currentWord := currentWord + chr;
        end
        else begin
            if (inWord) then begin
                AddToDictionary(currentWord);
                currentWord := '';
            end;
            inWord := false;
        end;
    end;
    SetLength(wordArray, currentArrayLength);
    CloseFile(inputFile);
end;
```

I use `{$codepage UTF8}` compiler directive as well. There are WideChar (2 byte) Russian symbols in the reading file and I can not get them with the way like above `(*read(inputFile, chr)*)`, looks like I read only first byte of symbol with this way. If I directly assign some symbol to my `WideChar` variable and then call my IsAlpha function it works well, for example:

```
chr: WideChar;
chr := 'Й';
IsAlpha(chr); // true
```

I need to extract somehow the symbol from file.

Comment: Just a note: `raise Exception.Create(...); Exit` has the same effect as `raise Exception.Create(...)` alone. No need for that `Exit`.

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag since this is clearly a lazarus / fpc question